# Max scrollable time for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll, infinite-scroll

What is the max scrollable time that can be set for scrolling search ?

Documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one-value-fits-all value of max scroll time.

Scan & Scroll is meant to scan through a large number of records in chunks. The max value for each chunk has to be obtained by incremental increases till you hit the breaking as it depends on your cluster resources,network latency and cluster load.

We had a 3 node test setup with about 1 billion records and 1 TB of data. I was able to scroll through the entire index with scroll size 5000 and timeout 5m. However, there were lots of timeouts with those values. From our analysis,we observered that scroll timeouts were heavily dependent on `cluster load` and `network latency`. So we finally settled on 3500 size and 4m timeout.

So i would recomend the following-

- Incrementally increase the size and timeout values to get the max value for your network.
- Once you have the max value, reduce it a notch to accommodate for failures due to cluster load & latency

Comment: Yeah, I guess I have to sweat it out. The other pain is we used AWS hosted Elastic Search which defaults query time outs to 30s and they cannot change it.

Answer (score 11):

If you're asking this kind of question you're probably not using Scroll in ES how it was intended.  You want to use scroll when you know for sure that you need to return **ALL** matching records.

## Great use case for Scroll

I want to pull back 1,000,000 records from ES to be written to a CSV file.  This is a perfect use case for scroll.  You need to return 1M rows, but you don't want to return them all as 1 chunk from the database.  Instead you can chunk them into ~1000 record chunks, write the chunk to the CSV file, then get the next chunk.  Your scroll keep alive can be set to 1 minute and you'll have no problems.

## Bad use case for Scroll

A user is viewing the first 50 records and at some time in the future, they may or may not want to view the next 50 records.

For a use case like this you want to use the [Search After API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html)

Comment: I am using it to dump 33 M records to csv. The chunk I use is 100. If I set a very high size (10,000) in one "chunk", ES has to prepare these records in memory, it slows down and times out my requests. So this scrolling of 100 records with 1m scroll time works until 2 - 3 M records. At some point here, the requests time out. So if I setup a scroll time of 1m and hope to restart at this point, depending on the timeout my retries fail (scroll expires). 
So if I make scroll time as large as possible, I am covering for large timeouts. 
Does this make sense ?

Comment: The TTL value is the timeout **between** requests.  So if it takes 10 minutes to download 33M records, but each chunk takes 20 seconds, then a 1 minute timeout is perfect.  If you're seeing a timeout after 2-3M records it's because somewhere in your code it's taking longer than 1 minute **between** requests.

Also remember that each chunk request you need to specify the TTL again.

One last thing, a chunk size of 100 is pretty low, I'd start with 1000-5000.

Comment: It is the same code running in a loop. At 2 - 3M the query is so slow that it times out. I got timeout out for 2000 size after 0.5M records were fetched, hence 100 is safe spot. The time taken for query at-least linearly(may be exponential) increases with the records retrieved.

At 100 size I hit the "timeout >scroll time" very late.

Comment: I would venture that there is an issue with your scroll continue code.  The time to setup a scroll might be a few seconds, but then each subsequent request for the next chunk will happen in constant time.  Are you sure you're not creating a new scroll each time (just a guess)?